# How does one smooth the cursor in a scaled flex/flash application?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex3

I'm scaling my application to fit the browser window. I'm also defining my own cursor using a bitmap and CursorManager.setCursor.

The problem: when my app scales, the cursor bitmap is jagged. Is there a way to smooth the bitmap that is use?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you're scaling your root display object(e.g., stage), which means the cursor also gets scaled. You probably want to scale a child container instead, which means the cursor won't scale. I'm guessing you don't want the cursor to change sizes anyway.

Otherwise, you can look at using an svg file (or a swf image) since they're based on vectors and scale properly. You can also look at trying to smooth the bitmap using the bitmapData draw function. [(http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()))